# np.take() ValueError after upgrading Python versions

Tags: python, numpy

After upgrading to the most recent version of Python, this code has begun to throw an error.

```
diameter2D = [[] for i in range(len(masks))]
noSN = []

np.take(diameter2D, noSN)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[86], line 1
----> 1 type(np.take(diameter2D, noSN))

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in take(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.conda/envs/jupyter_3.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:190, in take(a, indices, axis, out, mode)
     93 @array_function_dispatch(_take_dispatcher)
     94 def take(a, indices, axis=None, out=None, mode='raise'):
     95     """
     96     Take elements from an array along an axis.
     97 
   (...)
    188            [5, 7]])
    189     """
--> 190     return _wrapfunc(a, 'take', indices, axis=axis, out=out, mode=mode)

File ~/.conda/envs/jupyter_3.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:54, in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     52 bound = getattr(obj, method, None)
     53 if bound is None:
---> 54     return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 try:
     57     return bound(*args, **kwds)

File ~/.conda/envs/jupyter_3.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:43, in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     41 except AttributeError:
     42     wrap = None
---> 43 result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
     44 if wrap:
     45     if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (44,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

This code was working prior to upgrading the Python version I had, but now it throws an error. I've tried using different axes, casting the lists as numpy arrays, and flattening the 2D list, but that doesn't do what I want. However, the code does run without error when `diameter2D` is a 1D list, just the output isn't what I want.

Comment: What is your expected/desired output? It doesn't raise an error in Python 3.10.6, numpy 1.22.4. Are the arrays/lists supposed to be empty or is that just your example input?

Comment: Hi! My desired output is to obtain all the lists in diameter2D at indices that are in noSN. Noo sorry, the arrays are filled when I run the code, just an example of what the structures look like!

Comment: Also apologies, I checked and it's Python 3.8

Comment: `np.array([[] for i in range(len(masks))])` makes a (n,0) shaped numeric dtype array.  That isn't the problem.  What exactly is your list "filled" with?  The error tells me you are creating a "ragged" array, something that in earlier versions would have produced an object dtype array (possibly with a warning).  Give `take` arrays, not lists.

Comment: Ohh I read about ragged arrays, I think you're right! The list is filled with floats.

Comment: Ohhh, so if I put np.array() in front when initializing it should be okay? Let me try now!

Comment: `take` expects an array, or tries to convert the input to an array.  By making it an array first, you have more control - or at least the option of working around the problems.  `numpy` has been tightening up so loose ends caused by 'ragged' inputs.